# MAX 6675 K-type unstable to say the least

Tags: amplifier, thermocouple

have two breakout boards with MAX6675. I have 3 different K-type thermo elements. The MAX is connected to an AVR (atmega8) for communication, driver my own, communicates to PC on UART.

Now none of the combinations of MAX and K-type element works well. The only main feature is that you cannot touch the cable or probe, or even come in vincinity of the cable/probe with my hand without values falling drastically, eventually going to 0 if you take hold of the cable.
Also the value drifts substancially when just left alone.

Dont get any grip of whats going on, is the amp oscillating, and then why, what to try for remedy.

Thanks for any help  (not allowed to tag with the only useful tag MAX6675)

Comment: The word is 'unstable'. How are you powering the circuit? Have you tried powering from batteries?

Comment: 1st; onboard 7805 +wallwart12, then tower PC power unit, 5V lead. not tested bat though. strange: The total loss readings when touch, then immediate recover...

Comment: right; slip; "instabil" in swe :)

Comment: well it seems that there are issues,yes Kartman, will try bat, however: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/max6675-type-k-thermocouple-huge-fluctuation/376551/9  doesnt really give much hope "too bad it doesnt work".

Comment: How have you wired the device? How have you validated your 'driver'? Your link was to someone that was doing something silly.

Comment: hmm. the RPCoyle person in the link had abandoned the MAX for plain opamp. I have tried bat now, identical activity. Well Im a bit intermittant designer/coder; think I verified back in jan, when on breadboard. The values come and get stable at some level, well fairly at least, but differs between starts, have therefore difficulty in seeing that the driver would be (main) problem, values are also not random but fairly continuous as they come and go.

Comment: Show us some pictures wirh your setup. Is max6675 from reputable supplier or some cheap counterfeit clone ?

Comment: There could be a number of problems. You want to rule out the more obvious ones so that leaves hopefully only one problem. Power supply and connections would be the first port of call, review the 'driver' code to eliminate possible issues there then that leaves the chip/board. As @modoran mentions, there's counterfeit chips, so the performance of these is unknown. The recommended circuit for the max6675 shows one side of the thermocouple connected to 0V, so that should keep noise to a minimum, however, if there's a switchmode psu in the mix, then that can inject a significant signal.

Comment: Hi all, thx for input. Have tried with battery as said. And as per suggestion I guess that should be kind of noise free. Yes the breakout board and probably the chip is cheap, its, or rather both boards, I have two identical, are from aliexpress, yes I know, but thats where my budget lies. Possibly I should raise my level

Comment: cont:   I can try to see if my dumbphone will cooperate for a picture. Its a prototyping board with the Atmega8, a led, 3 straight parallell wires to a connector where the breakout board is plugged. I have had some notion that the parallell sck and data might interact, its like 4-5cm.

Comment: cont 2 It delivers values though my driver, and which are somewhat stable, but on varying levels, which do seem to have some correspondence to heat of probe, one probe (the more professional) gives a quite continous raise in temperature when held over candel, and the "strong emf" from some hundred C seem to make the "margin" for "touching" enought that I can hold the probe witout it going to zero. But it is very difficult to verify/calibrate, when the "low voltage" obtained by my calibration source, which is boiling water, will just be so unstable, and vanish when touching probe.